# Fail to imply _Reflectable protocol

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am reading [MirrorType](http://nshipster.com/mirrortype/) at nshipster,and trying to adopt it's code to Swift 2.1. Everything works fine until when I tried to custom the `_MirrorType`with :

```
extension WWDCSession : _Reflectable {
    func _getMirror() -> _MirrorType {
       return WWDCSessionMirror(self)
    }
}
```

An error occured :

> error: Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff58273e87).

And I found  out it's because the `init` method in `WWDCSessionMirror` was being called infinite times.

```
struct WWDCSessionMirror: _MirrorType {
private let _value: WWDCSession

init(_ value: WWDCSession) {
    _value = value
}

var value: Any { return _value }

var valueType: Any.Type { return WWDCSession.self }

var objectIdentifier: ObjectIdentifier? { return nil }

var disposition: _MirrorDisposition { return .Struct }

var count: Int { return 4 }

subscript(index: Int) -> (String, _MirrorType) {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        return ("number", _reflect(_value.number))
    case 1:
        return ("title", _reflect(_value.title))
    case 2:
        return ("track", _reflect(_value.track))
    case 3:
        return ("summary", _reflect(_value.summary))
    default:
        fatalError("Index out of range")
    }
}

var summary: String {
    return "WWDCSession \(_value.number) [\(_value.track.rawValue)]: \(_value.title)"
}

var quickLookObject: PlaygroundQuickLook? {
    print(summary)
    return .Text(summary)
}
}
```

I want to ask why it happened , and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_Reflectable and _MirrorType are not the droids you're looking for.

They are legacy types, which have been superseded by CustomReflectable (among others). The 2015 WWDC session about LLDB goes into some detail about this (disclaimer: I am the speaker of that part of that session, so conflict of interests all around :-)

But, anyway, the issue you're running into is because of this line:

```
_value = value
```

Since you're typing this line in your playground, that tells the playground logic to capture for display ("log" in playground parlance) the thing you're assigning. To do so, the playground uses the Mirror attached to that type. So, we go off and create one, which causes us to run

```
_value = value
```

again, which tells the playground logic to log value, which then means we create a Mirror, ...

You should first of all check if you can adopt Mirror and CustomReflectable instead of _MirrorType and if using those APIs fixes your problem. If it doesn't a possible workaround is to put the reflection support code in an auxiliary source file which will cause the playground logic to not log things inside of it.